# Add iTunes in app purchase via api call

Tags: ios, api, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm building an iOS app and would like to add and in-app-purchase programmatically from our custom CMS/Web-app.

I can't seem to find any reference a (JSON or alternative) API where I can push relevant data to iTunes Connect to create an in-app-purchase remotely.

Sorry, for the rubbish question. I have hunted for answers and can't seem to find anything. Does anyone know what options I have here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no official APIs for iTunes Connect or the Apple Developer Center. Either have a look at [Fastlane/Spaceship](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship) (Official/Open Source) or the [iTMSTransporter](http://help.apple.com/itc/appsspec/#/itcbce96a8e7) (Apple/XML).

Spaceship recently added the management of IAPs. With iTMSTransporter you can upload IAPs within the XML package of apps.

Comment: Legendary. Thanks very much for the response. Awesome and very useful.